# Change all values of an array without a loop construct

Tags: php, arrays, functional-programming, callback

I have the following array in php:

```
$a = [0, 4, 5, 7];
```

I would like to increment all the values without writing a loop (for, foreach...)

```
// increment all values
// $a is now array(1, 5, 6, 8)
```

Is it possible in php?

And by extention, is it possible to call a function on each element and replace that element by the return value of the function?

For example:

```
$a = doubleValues($a); // array(0, 8, 10, 14)
```

Comment: You could use [`array_walk()`](http://php.net/array_walk). But that's still a loop internally, even if you don't note the `for` or `foreach` yourself.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

This is a job for [`array_map()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) (which will loop internally):

```
$a = array(0, 4, 5, 7);
// PHP 5.3+ anonmymous function.
$output = array_map(function($val) { return $val+1; }, $a);

print_r($output);
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 6
    [3] => 8
)
```

**Edit by OP:**

```
function doubleValues($a) {
  return array_map(function($val) { return $val * 2; }, $a);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Yeah this is possible using the PHP function [array_map()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) as mentioned in the other answers.This solutions are completely right und useful. But you should consider, that **a simple foreach loop will be faster and less memory intense**. Furthermore it grants a better readability for other programmers and users. Nearly everyone knows, what a foreach loop is doing and how it works, but most PHP users are not common with the array_map() function.

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = array(0, 4, 5, 7);
function val($val) { return $val+1; }
$arr = array_map( 'val' , $arr );
print_r( $arr );
```

See it [here](http://codepad.org/uKP7jwOp)